# wordpress fancybox responsive mobile or pc version

Tags: mobile

I just want to have 2 types of fancybox size. 
for mobiles version width: 95%, height: 85%
for pc version - width: 85%, height: 80%
How can I set these 2 versions up? 
should I handle in php with 2 script or is there anyway to modify (handle) in a script?

```
   jQuery(".openf").fancybox({
   'width'   : '95%',
   'height' : '85%',
   'autoScale' : false,
   'transitionIn'    : 'none',
   'transitionOut'   : 'none',
   'type'    : 'iframe'
   });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am presuming you are using the [Easy Fancybox plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-fancybox/), or some equivalent plugin. Your problem could be solved by applying custom css after Fancybox has loaded, as suggested by the plugin author [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-easy-fancybox-customising-easy-fancybox-using-css-or-whatever?replies=8). In essence, you can use media-queries to specify the size of the Fancybox to be different on various devices. See for example [this](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/) article as an introduction on using media-queries.

Also, per the Easy Fancybox FAQ, a fix could be:

> **The lightbox does not look good on mobile devices. What can I do about that?**
>
> The FancyBox 1.3.4 script that is used in thsi plugin was not
>   developed with mobile devices in mind. The only way around this issue
>   is currently to disable FancyBox for small screen sizes. You can do
>   this by adding a text widget in your sidebar with the following code
>   snippet.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(window.innerWidth < 500 || window.innerHeight < 500 || window.outerWidth < 500 || window.outerHeight < 500 ) {
  jQuery(document).off('ready gform_post_render', easy_fancybox_handler);
};
</script>
```

> Tweak the value 500 to target other screen sizes.

Hope this helps, best of luck!